# jw player resume after refresh

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

how to make the JW Player have a "resume" or "remember" function which marks position of last

play position of movie and remembers it when you come back to watch video again?  So, if a

viewer stopped watching a movie at 36:25 minutes on a 2 hour movie and had to go offline, when

they returned to watch movie, the JW player would open to the correct position and "resume"

play.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:
http://osric.com/chris/jwplayer/jwplayer5.4/ontime.html
The JavaScript from that page is as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
jwplayer("container").setup({
    file:"playlist.xml",
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
        events: {
        onTime: function(event) {
            $('#timer').html(Math.floor(event.position));
        }
    }
});
```

That code sets an element with the id of "timer" to be the value of the current position.
You could then create either a cookie to save the variable from the JS.

**Edit**
You can use this link to help with the cookie function:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    jwplayer("container").setup({
    file:"playlist.xml",
    height: 300,
    width: 400,
        events: {
        onPause: function(event) {
            setCookie(event.position);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx sir :)  but can i use onpause and onplay events??

Comment: I've just edited my original answer. It should be more useful to you. I've provided a link (in my edit) to help you create a function to save a cookie. If you want to add onPlay you can simply copy and paste the onPause event (you can have both at the same time), and then create a getCookie function (again with the link) within that. I hope this helps.