# JW player play/Pause button refreshing browser

Tags: sitecore, jwplayer

having an annoying problem with JW Player. If I click on the video it will pause and play generally fine however if I use the pause and play button it refreshes my browser. Seems to effect browsers using the HTML5, fine in Flash. Can't come across anyone reporting the same problem. Running the files from videos in Sitecore Media Library. I was having a problem in IE9, saying 'error loading media: file could not be played' I sometimes get this in Chrome after trying to resume playback of video. Any ideas? Have encoded the video in Handbrake as iphone4 and universal MP4 with web optmise ticked.

Not done anything that special with the Javascript and using default skin.

Comment: look at this link i think it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929691/jw-player-resume-after-refresh

Comment: I think I know what this is, but to confirm, do you have a sample link?

Comment: I think this was a bug, and the work around is posted here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/30820/hosting-jwplayer-inside-of-a-form-tag-causes-postback

Comment: @EthanLongTail not sure if I am using this right, do I put this in the setup bit or can I just call it on the page between a <script></script>?

Comment: Just call it on the page between a <script></script>